# How to block user access to download stream video?

Tags: wordpress, apache, video-streaming

I have a WordPress site.
Every user who has IDM(internet download manager) or something like that, could download my stream video.
This icon appears beside each video and users can simply download videos.

[image: video downloader botton]

I know there is no way to stop all user.
but is there any way to disappear this icon from their web browser
or make a way to not recognize video at the first look?

Comment: You gotta live with it, man. Today is IDM, tomorrow it'll be something else. People will always find a way around.

Comment: my problem is the green button. because I have a lots video in one page. and at the first look, it messes up my page style! a page with a lot of green buttons!